# Why is my copy constructor being called when I try to add an element to my vector?

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor

I am trying to add a customer to my vector and when I run my program the copy constructor is called. I am doing an assignment where I need a vector of customers and have to be able to add customers, display customers, find customers and load/store the data. Have I created the vector wrong? I am only new to c++ and really unsure about vectors.

Code from Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Customer.h"
using namespace std;


void OutputFileStream();
void parseLine(const string& str);
void InputFileStream();
void save(vector<Customer> customers);
void load(vector<Customer>& customers);
void addCustomer(vector<Customer>& vect);
void displayAll(vector<Customer>& customers);
//void printActions();
vector<Customer> customers;

void OutputFileStream()
{
    cout << "Creating and writing to file: Customer.txt" << endl;

    ofstream outStream("customers.txt");  // write mode (overwrites existing data)

    if (outStream.good())
    {
        int customerID = 150033;
        outStream << "This is a line of text.\n";
        outStream << "This is another line of text.\n";
        outStream << "This is a line of text.\n";
        int numOfPurchases = 4;
        int purchases = 0;
        outStream << customerID << "Mr" << "Jack" << "New" << numOfPurchases << purchases << endl;
        //int *purchases = customers[0].getPurchases();
        outStream.close(); //  close file
        cout << "File written.\n" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
}

void parseLine(const string& str) {

    stringstream strStream(str); //create string stream from the string
   // int customerID;
    string title;
    string name;
    string type;
    //int numOfPurchases;
    //int purchases;
    string s;
   
    int customerID = 150033;
    getline(strStream, s, ';');
    customerID = stoi(s);

    getline(strStream, title, ';');
    getline(strStream, name, ';');
    getline(strStream, type, ';');

    int numOfPurchases = 4;
    getline(strStream, s, ';');
    numOfPurchases = stoi(s);

    int purchases = 0;
    getline(strStream, s, ';');
    purchases = stoi(s);
    int* purchasesArray = new int[3];
    purchasesArray[0] = (purchases & (255 << 16)) >> 16;
    purchasesArray[1] = (purchases & (255 << 8)) >> 8;
    purchasesArray[2] = purchases & 255;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << purchasesArray[i];
    }

    cout << " CustomerID: " << customerID << "Title:" << title << " Name: " << name << " Type:" << type << " Number of Purchases: " << numOfPurchases << "Purchases: " << purchases << endl;
}

void InputFileStream() {
    cout << "Reading from a semi-colon delimited txt file" << endl;

    string line;
    ifstream inStream("customers.txt"); //opens file as an input file stream
    if (inStream.good()) //if the file is opened successfully and not empty
    {
        while (getline(inStream, line)) //reads line until false return
        {
            parseLine(line);

        }
        inStream.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "unable to open file or the file is empty!";
}

void save(vector<Customer> customers)
{
    ofstream out("customers.txt");
    if(out)
    {
        for (Customer& c : customers)
        {
            out << c.save();
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error Writing to File" << endl;
    }
}

void load(vector<Customer>& customers)
{
    ifstream in("customers.txt");
    if (in) {
        string line;
        while (!in.eof())
        {
            getline(in, line);
            if (line != "")
            {
                Customer c;
                c.parse(line);
                customers.push_back(c);
            }
        }
    }
}

void addCustomer(vector<Customer>& customers) {
    Customer customer;
    cin >> customer;
    customers.push_back(customer);
    
}

void displayAll(vector<Customer>& customers)
{
    cout << "\nvector contains:\n";
    for (Customer c : customers)
    cout << c.getCustomerID() << " " << c.getTitle() << c.getName() << c.getNumOfPurchases() << c.getPurchases() << c.getType() << endl;
    cout << endl;; //same as calling customer
}
//
//int getCustomerByPurchaseNumber(int numOfPurchases) {
//    vector<Customer> customers;
//    int pos = -1;
//    for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
//        if (customers.at(i).getNumOfPurchases() == numOfPurchases) {
//            return i;
//        }
//    }
//    return pos;
//}
//
//void findCustomerByPurchaseNumber(vector<Customer>& customers) {
//    vector<Customer> customers;
//    int numOfPurchases;
//    cout << "Please Enter Your Purchase Number:" << endl;
//    cin >> numOfPurchases;
//    int pos = customers.get(pos);
//    getCustomerByPurchaseNumber(numOfPurchases);
//    if (pos == -1) {
//        cout << "Number of Purchase Not Found! "  << endl;
//          return customers;
//    }
//    else {
//        cout << "Number Of Purchase Found! " << endl;
//
//        return customers* = customers;
//    }
//    
//}


int main()
{
    vector<Customer> customers;
    Customer c1 = { 150031, "Mr", "John", 5, 333,362,341, "New" };
    customers.push_back(c1);
   
    //InputFileStream();
    

   /* Customer customer;

    customer.setCustomerID(150032);
    customer.setTitle("Mr");
    customer.setName("Joey");
    customer.setNumOfPurchases(3);
    customer.setPurchases(366, 352, 334);
    customer.setType("New");

    cout << customer.getCustomerID() << endl;
    cout << customer.getTitle() << endl;
    cout << customer.getName() << endl;
    cout << customer.getNumOfPurchases() << endl;
    cout << customer.getPurchases() << endl;
    cout << customer.getType() << endl;
   */
  
    return 0;
   
     
}
```

Code from Customer.cpp:

```
#include "Customer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;

//default constructor
Customer::Customer() {
}


//Full constructor
Customer::Customer(int customerID, string title, string name, int numOfPurchases, int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3, string type)
{
    this->customerID = customerID;
    this->title = title;
    this->name = name;
    this->numOfPurchases = numOfPurchases;
    purchases = new int[3];
    purchases[0] = purchase1;
    purchases[1] = purchase2;
    purchases[2] = purchase3;
    this->type = type;
}

Customer::Customer(const Customer& source) //copy constructor
{
    cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;
    this->customerID = source.customerID;
    this->title = source.title;
    this->name = source.name;
    this->numOfPurchases = source.numOfPurchases;
    this->purchases = new int[3];
    purchases[0] = source.purchases[0];
    purchases[1] = source.purchases[1];
    purchases[2] = source.purchases[2];
    this->type = source.type;
}

//overloaded assignment operator=
Customer& Customer::operator= (Customer& otherCustomer)
{
    cout << "Overloaded assignment operator= called" << endl;

    //self-assignment guard
    if (this == &otherCustomer)
        return *this;  //refernce to the same object

   // copy data from the source (rhs) to this object (the destination)
    name = otherCustomer.name;

    //must make a new scores object to store a copy of the other student 
    if (purchases != nullptr)
        delete[] purchases;

    purchases = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        purchases[i] = otherCustomer.purchases[i];
    }

    //return this existing object so we can chain this operator 
    return *this;
}

string Customer::save()
{
    stringstream out;
    out << this->customerID << ";";
    out << this->title << ";";
    out << this->name << ";";
    out << this->type << ";\n";
    out << this->numOfPurchases  << ";";
    int* purchases = 0;
    
    out.flush();
    return out.str();
}

void Customer::parse(string line)
{
    stringstream in(line);
    string customerIDLine;
    getline(in, customerIDLine, ';');
    customerID = stoi(customerIDLine);
    getline(in, title, ';');
    getline(in, name, ';');
    getline(in, type, ';');

    string numOfPurchases;
    getline(in, numOfPurchases, ';');
    int s = stoi(numOfPurchases);

    int* purchasesArray = new int[3];
    purchasesArray[0] = (s & (255 << 16)) >> 16;
    purchasesArray[1] = (s & (255 << 8)) >> 8;
    purchasesArray[2] = s & 255;
}  

void Customer::addCustomer(vector<Customer>& customers )
{
    //after read data 
    int customerID;
    cout << "Please Enter Customer ID: " << endl;
    cin >> customerID; 
    string title;
    cout << "Please Enter Title: " << endl;
    getline(cin, title);
    string name;
    cout << "Please Enter Name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    string type;
    cout << "Please Enter Type: " << endl;
    getline(cin, type);
    int numOfPurchases;
    cout << "Please Enter Number of Purchases: " << endl;
    cin >> numOfPurchases;
    int purchase1;
    cout << "Please Enter First Purchase: " << endl;
    cin >> purchase1;
    int purchase2;
    cout << "Please Enter Second Purchase: " << endl;
    cin >> purchase2;
    int purchase3;
    cout << "Please Enter Third Purchase: " << endl;
    cin >> purchase3;
    Customer c;
    customers.push_back(c);
    //Customer c();
}


Customer::~Customer() {
    cout << "Destructor ~Customer called" << endl;
    delete[] purchases;
}

// Overloaded insertion operator  (Outputs Character object data as an output stream)
// Defined in header file as a  "friend" function, as it is not a member function
//
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Customer& customer)
{
    cout << "Customer details ( output by insertion operator<< )" << endl;
    cout << "Customer ID: " << customer.customerID << endl;
    cout << "Title: " << customer.title << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << customer.name << endl;
    cout << "Number of purchases: " << customer.numOfPurchases << endl;
    cout << "Purchases: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0) cout << ",";
        cout << customer.purchases[i];
    }
    cout << "Type: " << customer.type << endl;
    
    return out;
}


istream& operator>> (istream& in, Customer& customer)
{
    cout << "Enter Customer details ( using the extraction operator>> )" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Customer ID: " << endl;
    cin >> customer.customerID;
    cout << "Enter Title: " << endl;
    getline(cin, customer.title);
    cout << "Enter Name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, customer.name);
    cout << "Enter Number of Purchases: ";
    cin >> customer.numOfPurchases; 
    cout << "Enter Purchases: ";
    cin >> customer.purchases[0];
    cin >> customer.purchases[1];
    cin >> customer.purchases[2];
    cout << "Enter Type";
    getline(cin, customer.type);
    cout << endl;

    return in;
}

int Customer::getCustomerID()
{
    return customerID;
}

string Customer::getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

string Customer::getName()
{
    return name;
}

int Customer::getNumOfPurchases()
{
    return numOfPurchases;
}

int* Customer::getPurchases()
{
    return purchases;
}

string Customer::getType()
{
    return type;
}

void Customer::setCustomerID(int customerID)
{
    if (customerID < 1) {
        cout << "Customer ID has to be equal to 1 or more" << endl; //Changed all the "throw invalid_argument" messages to cout as they were causing an issue with my main.cpp file and an abort message kept appearing every time I ran my main.cpp file.
    }
    this->customerID = customerID;
}

void Customer::setTitle(string title)
{
    if (title.length() < 2) {
        cout << "Title has to be more than or equal to 2 characters" << endl;
    }
    this->title = title;
}

void Customer::setName(string name)
{
    if (name.length() < 4) {
        cout << "Length of name should be more than or equal to 4 characters" << endl;
    }
    this->name = name;
}

//Got help ith this on stack overflow as I was using "&&" instead of using "||" for the if statement
void Customer::setNumOfPurchases(int numOfPurchases)
{
    if(numOfPurchases <0 || numOfPurchases > 10000){
        cout << "Number of purchases should be between 0 to 10000" << endl;
    }
    this->numOfPurchases = numOfPurchases;
}

void Customer::setPurchases(int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3)
{
    if (purchase1 < 0 || purchase2 < 0 || purchase3 < 0) {
        cout << "Purchases must be more than or equal to zero" << endl;
    }
}

//Got help from stack overflow on comparing strings as I originally didnt use "type.compare"
void Customer::setType(string type) {
    if (type.compare("New") !=0 || type.compare("Either") !=0) {
        cout << "Type of purchase has to be New or Either" << endl;
    }
}
```

Code from Customer.h:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string>
#include <vector>

class Customer
{
private:
    int customerID;
    string title;
    string name;
    int numOfPurchases;
    int* purchases;
    string type;

public:
    Customer(); // default constructor
    Customer(int customerID, string title, string name, int numOfPurchases, int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3, string type);
    
    //copy overload assignment
    Customer& operator=(Customer& otherCustomer);
    Customer(const Customer& source);

    string save();
    void parse(string line);
    void addCustomer(vector<Customer>& customers);
    ~Customer(); //destructor


    //Getters and Setters
    void setCustomerID(int customerID);
    void setTitle(string title);
    void setName(string name);
    void setNumOfPurchases(int numOfPurchases);
    void setPurchases(int purchase1, int purchase2, int purchase3);
    void setType(string type);

    int getCustomerID();
    string getTitle();
    string getName();
    int getNumOfPurchases();
    int* getPurchases();
    string getType();

    void printCustomer() {
        cout << customerID << "," << title << "," << name << "," << numOfPurchases << "," << purchases << "," << type << endl;
    }

    

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Customer& customer); // overloaded operator<<
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Customer& customer); // overloaded operator >>
};
```

Comment: How else would the element get into the vector?

Comment: why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: i'm confused, is the copy constructor meant to be called and then i print the vector? @user253751 really sorry if it's a stupid question but i'm new to c++.

Comment: You care about the copy constructor of your own custom classes. You shouldn't care about internal mechanics of classes, like `vector`, provided by the Standard Library (STL). The latter work out-of-the-box once you `#include <vector>` at the beginning of your file.

Comment: Objects can't be moved. When you add an object to a vector it creates a new object in the vector which is a copy of the original object.

Comment: Note: `Customer& operator=(Customer& otherCustomer);` should be `Customer& operator=(const Customer& otherCustomer);` - Why are you using an `int*` for `purchases` btw?

Comment: Why is `purchases` a pointer when you always allocate three elements for it? Why not `int purchases[3];`? And if you really want its size to be dynamic, why not use `std::vector<int> purchases;`? In both these cases, you could then follow the rule of *zero* and omit copy-operators as well as the destructor.

Comment: @TedLyngmo In the assignment brief my lecture wants the variable "purchases" to be of type integer* and point to a dynamic array

Comment: @A6423 How odd when you are using a `std::vector` for storing the customers...

Comment: @TedLyngmo The brief says "a vector of customers"

Comment: @A6423 Yeah, and I wonder why you aren't allowed to use a vector for the purchases too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yea i'm not sure either, they just want us to add customers to the vector, including the customers in the txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vectors hold objects. If you have an object outside of the vector there is no way to have that same object inside the vector. You can move from one instance to one in the vector (that will move the instances inner parts, but there are still two instances).  `push_back` does make a copy of its parameter when it cannot be moved from.

As you have a constructor that takes all necessary parameters, you can use `emplace_back` to avoid the copy and construct the instance right in place in the vector:

```
customers.emplace_back( customerID, title, name, numOfPurchases, purchase1, purchase2, purchase3, type);
```

Comment: This got rid of the copy constructor being called! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `std::vector<Customer>` holds the element by value so just using `std::vector::push_back` will copy your local object into the vector.

To mitigate this you could either implement move semantics and move the the `Customer` object like this:

```
    #include <utility>
    ....
    Customer c;
    c.parse(line);
    customers.push_back(std::move(c));
```

or construct the object in-place:

```
    // Post c++17 you could use `push_back()` here as well as 
    // c++17 has mandatory copy elision.
    customers.emplace_back(Customer{}); // or customers.emplace_back(); only
    customers.back().parse(line);
```

Both solutions require c++11.

You could also store a reference/pointer and allocate the object on the heap.

```
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Customer>> customerVector;
    customer_vector.push_back(std::make_unique<Customer>());
    // or customer_vector.push_back(std::make_shared<Customer>());
```

Or

```
    std::vector<Customer*> customerVector;
    // Beware for memory leaks, needs to be deleted.
    // Basically never use code like this post c++11).
    customer_vector.push_back(new Customer{});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am going to try this now! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you check reference on [std::vector<T,Allocator>::push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) object can be added to vector either by being copied (option1) or being moved (option 2).

So you can create a [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) for your customer class:

```
class_name ( class_name && );
```

And then call [push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)  using that move consturctor (option 2) on vector:

```
void push_back( T&& value );
```